# How to get n-length Boolean array with conditions on X amount of 'True' values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, python-itertools, boolean-logic

I have the following list of events that have a binary outcome (i.e. 1 or 0):

```
events=['A', 'B', 'C']
outcomes=[True,False]
```

in each scenario, only one of these outcomes can be True. Is there a way to get an array like:

```
array=([True,False,False],[False,True,False], [False,False,True])
```

i know i can use itertools product with repeat but this will produce unwanted scenarios like [True,True,True] etc. in the array. ideally i would not have to filter it down as i expect my 'events' list to be much longer than the above.

Any one have any ideas? I can have 1 or 0 values in the array instead, I am not fussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a generator to do it yourself.

```
def one_true(length):
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        lst = [False] * length
        lst[i] = True
        yield lst
        i +=1

print(list(one_true(3)))
```

This seems fairly trivial since your `True` just needs to "crawl" across the array.

If you want to include a case where they are all `False` just add `yield [False] * length` at the end.

```
def one_true(length):
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        lst = [False] * length
        lst[i] = True
        yield lst
        i +=1
    yield [False] * length

print(list(one_true(3)))
```

And from your example:

```
events = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print(list(one_true(len(events))))
```

Or if you want to be more concise you could use a comprehension with a custom function.

```
def insert_true(lst, index):
    lst[index] = True
    return lst
events = ['A', 'B', 'C']
length = len(events)
foo = [insert_true([False] * length, i) for i in range(length)]

print(foo)
```

Comment: worked a charm, thanks! used the insert_true function. this also looks to work in case interested, answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374372/python-permutations-obtaining-full-set-of-outcomes-with-conditions